# Can we execute a BATCH(.bat) file from a .dll? I am not able to do so

Tags: batch-file, automation, dll, asp.net

I have an application where you can create custom dll's for the purpose of alerting and monitoring. I need to run a batch file through that custom dll so that previously running environments could close. Tried it using Process.Start("") but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
Process process;
String cmd1=@"D:\Bot1.bat"
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + cmd1);
\\ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Comment: From a DLL doesn't matter.  Either you are executing code within a process or you aren't.  I can only assume that you had more than "" for Process.Start.. sure would have been helpful to see what you tried.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp) for running a batch file from c#.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas added the code which i tried for the reference.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas is it necessary to use Process.ExitCode().

Comment: If it's C# then more than likely you'd want to ask on SO but here's a related post you might find helpful.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes.. @Pimp_Juice_IT is correct.  This is a question better geared for SO.. and yes.. the exit code might help you.  Have you tried launching OTHER stuff via your command to make sure it works? (notepad.exe + <some_text_file>).. ??

Comment: I tried asking it on SO but the question was closed there and I was redirected here.